# How do I extract photos from a source folder into a destination folder?

Tags: python

I needed to create a program that extracts photos only from a predetermined source folder with many subfolders (and file types) and place the images into a pre-determined destination folder and its subfolders.

The code only works for the first folder and I can't figure out how to make it work for the rest.

The content in each subfolder in the source folder is similar: a combination of different file types.

The attached image displays functionally what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

The below code is what I did. Again, it works, but only for the first folder.

```
import os
import shutil

# Set source directory
source_dir = r"C:\Users\YourUserName\SourceDirectory"

# Set destination directory
destination_dir = r"C:\Users\YourUserName\DestinationDirectory"

# Set file extension to filter for
file_extension = ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png"

# Iterate through folders in source directory
for foldername in os.listdir(source_dir):
    folder_path = os.path.join(source_dir, foldername)

    # Check if current path is a directory
    if os.path.isdir(folder_path):

        # Iterate over files in current directory
        for file in os.listdir(folder_path):

            # Check if file has the desired extension
            if file.endswith(file_extension):

                # Construct full path for source file and destination file
                source_file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file)
                destination_file_path = os.path.join(destination_dir, foldername, file)

                # Create directory in destination directory if it doesn't exist
                os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(destination_file_path), exist_ok=True)

                # Copy file to destination directory
                shutil.copy(source_file_path, destination_file_path)
                print(f"Copied {source_file_path} to {destination_file_path}")
```

Comment: Does it just stop or is there an error?

Comment: I take it you're not concerned with an arbitrary directory nesting depth.

Comment: As you iterate over each subdirectory, why are you creating the directory in the loop where you iterate over each file? Shouldn't this happen _once_ per subdirectory?

Comment: tadman: It just stops after 1 iteration.
Chris: I'm not sure I understand - I wanted to create folders as well if they weren't already created in the directory folder

Answer (score 0):

To itinerate between folders and subfolders, you can use `os.walk` instead:

```py
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source_dir):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(file_extension):

            # construct full path for source file and destination file
            filepath = subdir + os.sep + file

            destination_file_path = destination_dir + os.sep + dirs + os.sep + file

            # create directory in destination directory if it doesn't exist
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(destination_file_path), exist_ok=True)

            # copy file to destination directory
            shutil.copy2(source_file_path, destination_file_path)
            print(f"Copied {source_file_path} to {destination_file_path}")
```

You can also use it to save full path into a custom list:
*(And itinerate from here)*

```py
imagefiles = [os.path.join(root, name)
             for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source_dir)
             for name in files
             if name.endswith(file_extension)]
```

Comment: I used os.walk beforehand and ran into the same issue. It stops iterating after the 1st folder

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to achieve it using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pathlib.html)'s [`Path.rglob`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob):

```py
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import copy2


src = Path("src")
dst = Path("dst")

extensions = {".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png"}

for src_file in src.rglob("*"):
    if src_file.suffix in extensions:
        dst_file = dst / src_file.relative_to(src)
        dst_file.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        copy2(src_file, dst_file)
```